# Writing chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

From all documentation how to write chef recipe just only for directory creation is easy.

Maybe someone can help here with my task:

I have many servers on which are running different process and i need to create directories dependent on that process.

For example all my directories which will be:

```
/home/dir1 
/home/dir2 
/home/dir3 
/home/dir4 
/home/dir5.
```

On first server running process: dir1 dir2. on other server running process dir3 dir4.

So my question is how to create only directories which is related to only running process on that server and do not create directories for which server does not have any process.

Sorry for stupid question as i am absolutely new to this and do not have any experience in automation or coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have an if statement which would check on which node it is and / or an array with your hosts and if host x is found do directory 1 and 2, if host y is found than do directory 3 and 4.

Or other possibility might be to have a role which you could pass and if a host has that specific role go ahead and do dir 1 and 2 and so on.